# Cannot iterate over AbstractOrderedScalarSet 'i' before it has been constructed (initialized): '__iter__' is an attribute on an Abstract component

Tags: python, pyomo

I am trying to convert impedance into admittance by using a for loop, however it does not work and shows that

```
Cannot iterate over AbstractOrderedScalarSet 'i' before it has been constructed (initialized): '__iter__' is an attribute on an Abstract component and cannot be accessed until the component has been fully constructed (converted to a Concrete component) using AbstractModel.create_instance() or i.construct().
```

Therefore, do you have any idea how to resolve this?

```
model       = AbstractModel()
model.i     = Set()
model.j     = Set()

model.R = Param(model.i,mutable=True)
model.X = Param(model.i,mutable=True)
model.G = Param(model.i,mutable=True)
model.B = Param(model.i,mutable=True)

for model.i in model.i:
    model.G[model.i]=(model.R[model.i]/(model.R[model.i]**2+model.X[model.i]**2))
    break


model.Pd = Param(model.j,mutable=True)
model.Qd = Param(model.j,mutable=True)

model.vol = Var(model.j, bounds=(0.9,1.1),domain=Reals)
model.ang = Var(model.j, bounds=(-np.pi/6,np.pi/6),domain=Reals)
model.Pg  = Var(model.j, bounds=(0,2),domain=Reals)
model.Qg  = Var(model.j, bounds=(-1.5,1.5),domain=Reals)
```

Comment: Sorry, appearently I did not read the whole post. Why are you using pyomo to convert impedance into admittance? That's not the use for a modeling framework

Answer (score 1):

That's not the right way of write a `constraint` in `pyomo`

First at all, the way you're trying to write the constraint is bad, but even more important, you're mixing `Params` and `Constraints`. If `model.G` depends on some `params`, then `model.G` is not a param, but a `var`

The error is generated since you're trying to iterate over `model.i` `Set` which is not already constructed of initialized. You can whether to initialize the `Set` or just write the `Constraint` leaving implicit the dependency of `model.G` constraint upon `model.i` `Set`

```
model       = AbstractModel()
model.i     = Set()
model.j     = Set()

model.R = Param(model.i,mutable=True)
model.X = Param(model.i,mutable=True)
model.G = Var(model.i)
model.B = Param(model.i,mutable=True)


def compute_G(model, i):
    '''Compute the Var G which depend upon params R, X and B'''
    model.G[i] == model.R[i]/(model.R[i]**2+model.X[i]**2)
model.compute_G = Constraint(model.i, rule=compute_G, doc=compute_G.__doc__)


model.Pd = Param(model.j,mutable=True)
model.Qd = Param(model.j,mutable=True)

model.vol = Var(model.j, bounds=(0.9,1.1),domain=Reals)
model.ang = Var(model.j, bounds=(-np.pi/6,np.pi/6),domain=Reals)
model.Pg  = Var(model.j, bounds=(0,2),domain=Reals)
model.Qg  = Var(model.j, bounds=(-1.5,1.5),domain=Reals)
```